# How to replace a value in sql that sometimes has the character ; in it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Good afternoon stackoverflow!

I have a small problem with a stored procedure. I am trying to delete a single email address out of a long line of text in SQL but sometimes the email address ends with ; and sometimes it doesn't.

My code is this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spReports_DeleteSubscriber
@SubscriptionID varchar(50),
@Email varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Remove email from subscriptions
UPDATE Subscriptions
SET [ExtensionSettings] = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),[ExtensionSettings]),@Email + ';','')
Where SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID

-- Remove email from descriptions
UPDATE Subscriptions
SET [Description] = REPLACE([Description],@Email + ';','')
Where SubscriptionID = @SubscriptionID

END
GO
```

Do you think I would have to use the REPLACE method twice and try and remove the email address once with the ; and once without?

Comment: Is this the SSRS database itself? Or your own database?

Comment: Yes it is our SSRS database. I use the web service to remove subscriptions no problem but I am trying to make a stored procedure that only removes one email address at a time.

Comment: Can you not use distribution lists to make things easier?

Comment: I don't know if that would work because I am making it so users can add themselves to any report they want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a double REPLACE. It's simple and effective

Comment: Cheers man, its pretty ugly looking but its functional so thats all good :)